# Why sending binary data over gSOAP is too much slow?

Tags: c++, web-services, qt, gsoap

I am trying to send an image from a client application to server using gSOAP web services and C++. To this aim, I am using Qt and my client and server applications could operate on both Windows and Linux. The surprising part is that for a 1MB jpg image, it takes about 6 seconds to send the image from client to server running on the same machine on both Linux and Windows platforms. Is there something wrong with my application or any other web service technology will take the same time?

P.S. To send data, I am using the type **unsigned char ***.

**Edit 1:** How can I send binary data over gSOAP using base64 data type. As I've read the documentation, no data type is available in the .stub files.

Comment: Where are the client and server located? Especially, how are they located relative to each other? I.e. are they on a local network? Half-way around the world from each other?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg They are located on the same machine !

Comment: How much data is sent in total? (The image data might be sent base 64-encoded?)

Comment: is the transfer so slow or is there a function eating up a lot of time? use your prefered network monitor that the applicaiton utilizes the whole connection as well as your prefered profiler to see wich function slows your app down

Comment: It's almost 2016 and you're still using SOAP? Might as well program in COBOL while you're at it.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Not measured it yet ! Should I sent the data with base64 encoding?

Comment: @MrEricSir I have to use C++ and Qt. Please introduce me any better alternative if you know any!!!

Comment: I’m not saying you should, but given that SOAP is XML, I was just assuming that the data will be converted to base64 or the like eventually, which increases the amount of data transferred. Thus I’m asking if you measured how much data is actually sent. However, if it’s all on the local machine, the bottleneck is most probably on either the sender’s or the receiver’s side. I’d try with a profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSD base64Binary type is an XML schema-native raw binary type. Performance should be very good with `-DDEBUG` disabled (because message logging is slow!).

The gSOAP tools generate efficient XML serializers that push and pull base64 over the wire while converting from/to raw data directly.

Here are some numbers on a typical system, assuming low network overhead:

- Echo 1K base64 100 times (i.e. 200 messages with 1K base64): 
  `Elapsed real time = 140 (ms) CPU time = 120 user = 40 system = 80`
- Echo 100K base64 100 times (i.e. 200 messages with 100K base64): 
  `Elapsed real time = 820 (ms) CPU time = 450 user = 280 system = 170`
- Echo 1MB base64 100 times (i.e. 200 messages with 1MB base64): 
  `Elapsed real time = 5650 (ms) CPU time = 3730 user = 2740 system = 990`

Network bandwidth may be a factor in your performance.

PS. You may want to try `SOAP_IO_CHUNK` for chunked transfers. A more aggressive approach is to change `SOAP_BUFLEN` (normally 64K) to optimize socket buffer size (and recompile all sources that include `stdsoap2.h` to make sure the new buffer size is used).